# How to fix 'line 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")'

Tags: c, mpi, cluster-computing, mpich

I'm setting up a raspberry pi computer cluster, the master is running ubuntu on oracle VM VirtualBox. I've made a passwordless ssh between the master and the raspberry pi, then I've set up a shared directory using NFS. And I'm using MPI for C.

The passwordless ssh and NFS are working fine.

The problem is,
when executing the code on the machine that compiles it, the program behaves normally.
But when compiling the code on a machine and execute it on another machine I encounter this error:
`./mpi_hello: 1: ./mpi_hello: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`
Compilation command:
`mpicc -o mpi_hello mpi_hello.c`

Both machines has the same version of MPICH2

edit: added the compilation command

edit 2: apparently i compiled the code on a machine with different cpu architecture than the machine that is running it

Comment: Hi, perhaps run `file mpi_hello` to make sure the executable is recognized by the platform?

Comment: output: ``mpi_hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=77e8ed5641e40ad8c1dbda03ff305c7323394ed, not stripped`` for both machines

Comment: you should at least post the full `mpirun` command line

Comment: Is the machine you're running on an ARM CPU?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've added the ``mpirun`` command line

Comment: @jspcal my master machine is ``i386`` and the raspberry pi is ``armhf``

Comment: Are you trying to run an `armhf` binary on an `i 386` server ? That won't work ...

Comment: so all of my machines should have the same architecture. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can build two binaries and run the right one on each node

Comment: how can I do that? what is the ``mpirun`` command line?